# Tengo un problema cuando voy a generar los Models con Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer en .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Se supone que ingreso un comando en la Consola del Administrador de paquetes de Visual Studio 2019 y ese comando se encarga de generar los modelos, el comando es el siguiente:

```
Scaffold-DBContext "Server=<nombre_de_mi_servidor>;Database=<nombre_de_la_base_de_datos>;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

El error que me aparece en consola es este:

```
Cannot open database "<nombre_de_la_base_de_datos>" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user '<usuario_de_mi_computador>'.
```

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019, SQL Server 2019 y .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes cambiar el `Database` por `initial Catalog` y si usas el usuario de windows de localhost colocas `Integrated Security` :

```
 Scaffold-DBContext "Server=<nombre_de_mi_servidor>;Initial Catalog=<nombre_de_la_base_de_datos>;integrated security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciocó correctamente.